# Eclipse: Lower bar moved to right, how to undo?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I don't know if this is the right place for it.  Using Eclipse 4.6.2 on OSX, in the Java view, I used to have a bar on the bottom with Problems, Tasks, Console, Properties, etc. tab options.  This bar is now small icons on the right.  It appears on the bottom when I click on the right bar, but it disappears as soon as I click on any editing tab outside of it.  Clicking and dragging the bar to the bottom doesn't have any effect.  It has a restore-window style icon that doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm also finding that when I select a .java file, like in Problems or Call Hierarchy, it shows up on the bottom, when it used to pop up above the bottom section.

I've always gotten really confused whenever I've tried to mess with the default views/perspectives in Eclipse.  I probably made this happen by mistake.  I want to revert to the original behavior, but I'm not sure how.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top there should be a "window" menu bar. If you look in the window bar you should get a "reset perspective" option.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  This little thing has been nagging me for too long, and it was such an easy fix.